# Como aplicar fitro em um dataframe com base nos últimos caracteres de cada label?

Tags: python, pandas, rowfilter

Preciso aplicar um filtro de linhas em um dataframe com base nos últimos caracteres de um label, se conter ***BRL*** após o hífen. Ex.: ***BTC-BRL***. Alguém pode me ajudar?

- Dados atuais:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Dados após aplicar filtro:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é criar um filtro usando list comprehension:

```
filtro=[k[-3:]=='BRL' for k in df.A]

df=df[filtro]
```

Exemplo com banco de dados fictício:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

df=pd.DataFrame({"A":["BTC-BRL", "ETH-USD","WAVES-USD","ADA-BRL"]*5, "B":[random.choice(range(5)) for k in range(20)]})

print(df)
```

Banco antes:

```
            A  B
0     BTC-BRL  3
1     ETH-USD  1
2   WAVES-USD  2
3     ADA-BRL  1
4     BTC-BRL  3
5     ETH-USD  2
6   WAVES-USD  2
7     ADA-BRL  0
8     BTC-BRL  4
9     ETH-USD  0
10  WAVES-USD  4
11    ADA-BRL  0
12    BTC-BRL  4
13    ETH-USD  1
14  WAVES-USD  0
15    ADA-BRL  4
16    BTC-BRL  1
17    ETH-USD  1
18  WAVES-USD  4
19    ADA-BRL  1
```

Aplicando o filtro:

```py
filtro=[k[-3:]=='BRL' for k in df.A] 
df=df[filtro]
print(df)
```

Retorna:

```
          A  B
0   BTC-BRL  3
3   ADA-BRL  1
4   BTC-BRL  3
7   ADA-BRL  0
8   BTC-BRL  4
11  ADA-BRL  0
12  BTC-BRL  4
15  ADA-BRL  4
16  BTC-BRL  1
19  ADA-BRL  1
```

Comment: Era exatamente esta solução que estava buscando. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Um solução parecida com a do Lucas seria utilizando o `apply` com lambda

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[-3:] == 'BRL')]
```

Você também poderia utilizar `split`

```
df[df['A'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: x[1] == 'BRL')]
```

Em ambos os casos a saída é:

```
          A     B
0   BTC-BRL     2
3   ADA-BRL     1
4   BTC-BRL     2
7   ADA-BRL     4
8   BTC-BRL     1
11  ADA-BRL     3
12  BTC-BRL     0
15  ADA-BRL     1
16  BTC-BRL     4
19  ADA-BRL     0
```